# Why do we use an array of ones for a kernel in OpenCV?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

As I was reading the OpenCV docs today, I came across an interesting group of functions known as morphological transformations. While, I feel like I have a good grasp on the concepts of erosion and dilation, I am unable to understand why we use an array of 1's when performing the morphological transformation. For example, see the code below (referenced from [Open CV documentation](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html), where the author creates a kernel populated with ones when performing an erosion.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('j.png',0)
kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)
erosion = cv2.erode(img,kernel,iterations = 1)
```

After some research, I understood that the underlying workings of an erosion is simply a 2D convolution where the pixel in question is compared to neighboring pixels, and the local minimum of the picture underneath the kernel is set as the value of the pixel. Yet, this does not help me clarify why we set our kernel to hold one's in the first place. Why not 0's? Why not 255's? The kernel's values should not affect the convolution in any way right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You multiply kernel values by pixel values. If it is all 0, the output will be 0. If it is different than 1, the output is magnified by the value you put in kernel. It is 1, to keep the pixel value as is, and ALL 1 because that is what erosion filter does. Kernels are usually combinations of 1,0,-1 depending on the objective of kernel. So in your example, kernel of 5x5 1s is multiplied to 5x5 sub-images (which I think sums of pixel values of it).

Comment: ALL 1, does this mean the convolution result of a 3x3 filter has to be 9, which could be reached with a different convolution kernel that doesnt have 9 times the value 1, as well?

Comment: @Micka If I understand you correctly, the answer is yes. You can have two kernels that result in the same convolution on a sub-image. However, generally different kernels will result in different behavior over a span of full image (that includes variety of sub-images, in your example would be of size 3x3)